# tomcat can't execute cgi, and it shows contents as text

Tags: tomcat, cgi

my configuration as the below:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.servlets.CGIServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>debug</param-name>
<param-value>1</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>cgiPathPrefix</param-name>
<param-value>WEB-INF/cgi</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
<param-name>executable</param-name>
<param-value></param-value>
</init-param>
<param-name>passShellEnvironment</param-name>
<param-value>true</param-value>
<load-on-startup>5</load-on-startup>
</servlet>



<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>cgi</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/cgi-bin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

also add

but when I access url of my cgi, it will show contents as text, does not execute command in cgi, could you please point out what happens?

Comment: Show us the URL you are using.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/test/cgi/home.cgi

Comment: #!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"

echo  "<html>"
echo "<body>"
echo "HELLO WORLD"
echo "</body>"
echo "</html>"

Comment: In your `web.xml` you mapped the URL pattern `/cgi-bin/*` to the servlet, not `/cgi/*`.  Try this URL: `localhost:8080/test/cgi-bin/home.cgi` ... this should at least hit the servlet and hopefully you will see something.

Comment: Actually, I tried it, but the page will be blank
[$xdf webapps]$ tree test
test
|-- WEB-INF
|   |-- cgi-bin
|   |   `-- home.cgi
|   `-- web.xml
`-- cgi-bin
    `-- home.cgi

Comment: Or do you know how to sort folders of directory as desc, not asc? tomcat will use asc to sort folder as default

Comment: What does the `CGIServlet` do?

Comment: I only can see  the message in log ----  runCGI: bad header line "</html>"

Comment: Jun 14, 2016 12:06:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: cgi: runCGI: bad header line "<html>"
Jun 14, 2016 12:06:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: cgi: runCGI: bad header line "<body>"
Jun 14, 2016 12:06:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: cgi: runCGI: bad header line "HELLO WORLD"
Jun 14, 2016 12:06:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: cgi: runCGI: bad header line "</body>"
Jun 14, 2016 12:06:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: cgi: runCGI: bad header line "</html>"

Comment: This sounds like you are hitting the servlet.  Then you need to find out how to use it properly.

Comment: do you have any idea for this problem fixing?

Comment: There might be a problem with bash script. I will add script in answer section which can be used to create http response

Answer (score 0):

HTTP response in bash. Please note second line. It is important to differentiate between http headers and payload

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo "<html><head><title>Hello World</title></head>"
echo "<body>"
echo "Hello World!"
echo "</body></html>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but It seems it still does not work